# How to enable TalkBack without accessibility navigation?

Tags: text-to-speech, google-play-books

I have all the Google text-to-speech software installed, but the "Read Aloud" option is not enabled in Google Play Books for a book I bought from Google Play.

If I turn on the TalkBack feature then the "Read Aloud" option appears, but it is painful navigating the device since all the other accessibility options are now on.

Is there any way to enable the "Read Aloud" menu option without enabling all the other accessibility features that go along with it.

Comment: "Read Aloud unavailable" can appear if the book publisher has decided to not allow that feature.